# How can we get the value of textbox in QTP?

Tags: hp-uft

I am executing the automated test scripts in `UFT 12.5` I am new to UFT. Not very  familiar with codes.There is an edit box wherein i have to type the value "S05292". Example:

```
Browser(Browsername").Page("Pagename").WebEdit("ctl00$ConBody$txtPDNumber").Set "S05292"
```

The problem is my script fails at this step and does not type the value. Can somebody provide me with a solution which is easy to understand. I tried the below  two methods

*Method (1)*

```
a=Browser().page().webedit(ctl00$ConBody$txtPDNumber).getroproperty("value")
if a=="S05292" then
msgbox ("displayed message is S05292")
else
msgbox ("msg is not S05292")
end if
```

*Method (2)*

```
x = Browser("Browsername").Page("Pagename").Webedit("ctl00$ConBody$txtPDNumber").GetROProperty("value")
msgbox x
```

The error message that displays is

> Cannot identify the object "ctl00$ConBody$txtPDNumber" (of class WebEdit).
>   Verify that this object's properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Comment: The object `ctl00$ConBody$txtPDNumber` in your object repository is not matching any object on the screen.  Use the Object Spy to check the properties of the object at run time match with the properties you have learned into the OR.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Object Spy to get the properties of that text box at run time and then make sure they match up to the properties of that text box in your object repository that you defined.  Perhaps that don't match up or you didn't uniquely identify that text box.
If you don't want to use an object repository then you have to pass it a property at run time to uniquely identify it.  Some thing like:
Browser().page().webedit("developer name:=PDNumber").
Instead of a .set you can do a .type to set/type the value into the text box

Comment: Type does not apply to web applications. This is web based.Hence it will only take .set

Comment: I divided the script in different actions by calling to New Action and that did the work.   It did type the value  "S05292".

Comment: When it was one long script , it was unable to recognize the object properties , but breaking up into diff. Actions solved the issue